# How to uppercase login fields in auth component - cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to convert username and password fields that I'm using in my auth component to upper case, before the login action. I tried to set

```
text-transform:uppercase;
```

in my CSS, for inputs, and it worked. But the uppercased information do not go to the database. The strings will only be uppercased if I write them with capslock. Could someone give me an example (for newbies)?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my login action:

```
function login() {

if (!empty($this->data) && $this->Auth->user()) {
    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
}
```

}

Comment: that should work if its in the correct place.  you'll have to provide more code.

Comment: It works, visually... but the uppercased username and password, aren't what the database (firebird) is receiving, bexause the login don't work (all usernames and passwords in the data base are uppercased). But if I write the username and password with CAPSLOCK, everything works fine.

Comment: also - uppercasing passwords is like a really bad idea and compromises the security of your users' passwords! i am sure some of them won't appropriate that.

Comment: text-transform:uppercase will visibly change the change of the text but not the actual characters. They will be passed in original case but displayed as uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can uppercase in server-side php as demonstrated by @thecodeparadox, or you can do so with client-side javascript or if you're using jQuery, add it to your events.

html/javascript:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" onchange="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" />
  <input type="password" name="password" onchange="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" />
</form>​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/85HEy/2/

or html/jQuery:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='username'], input[name='password']").change(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    });
  });
</script>​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T9XbP/

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I put in my login.ctp: echo $form->input('username', array('onchange' => 'this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()'));